# How Content Document Should be Associated with Custom Object

Tags: lightning, feeditem, contentdocumentlink

I am trying to create File through ContentDocument . Once File is created want to associate with Custom Object

Want to understand what is best way to associate File with Custom Object

1. Use FeedItem Class
2. Use ContentDocumentLink

If any one has used it appreciate your input on advantage and limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question! Took me a while to figure it out few months ago, documentation is bit scarce...

Something like this should get you started. I'm passing `FeedItem` as parameter from Lightning so user has a chance to write something about the file. Actual content I'm pulling from a VF page (printable view of an order in PDF).

There were some quirks in the way Lightning was passing data to Apex (the `item.ParentId` was set in Lightning but being wiped out once it reached Apex) so I have to pass it & check it separately. Maybe they fixed it.

```java
@AuraEnabled
public static FeedItem savePdf(Id orderId, FeedItem item){

    // 1. Input validations
    if(item.ParentId == null){
        if(orderId == null || orderId.getSobjectType() != Schema.Order__c.sObjectType){
            throw new AuraHandledException('Please provide a valid Order Id');
        }
        item.ParentId = orderId;
    }

    // 2. Get order data
    Order__c o = [SELECT Name,
            (SELECT ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title 
            FROM ContentDocumentLinks
            WHERE ContentDocument.FileType = 'PDF'
            LIMIT 50)
        FROM Order__c
        WHERE Id = : orderId];

    insert item;

    // 2. Retrieve the document's payload, save it as Chatter File.

    ContentVersion file = getOrderPdf(o);

    // There's a chance a PDF was already generated for this order. Try to look through links between this order and Chatter Files
    // and if there's one with identical filename - add this document as new version instead of uploading fresh doc.
    // It's far from perfect but should make searching for order pdfs easier.
    // Better to see one instance of "Order 123" version 7 in search results than 7 different records.
    if(!o.ContentDocumentLinks.isEmpty()){
        for(ContentDocumentLink cdl : o.ContentDocumentLinks){
            if(cdl.ContentDocument.Title == file.Title){
                file.ContentDocumentId = cdl.ContentDocumentId;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    insert file;

    // 3. Final tweak - link the Chatter posts and Files using many-to-many helper object
    insert new FeedAttachment(
        FeedEntityId = item.Id,
        RecordId = file.Id,
        Type = 'CONTENT'
    );
    return item;
}
```

Comment: For FeedItem we use parentId where as ContentDocumentLink we use LinkedEntityID So one thing I was thinking that Security wise Parent-child relationship is maintained by FeedItem where as Same may not be the Case ContentDocumentLink

Comment: If you'll delete the file, the FeedItems will stay in the chatter feed (including the text user has typed if any) but the link in them will be broken. It'll says something about document not being accessible if I recall correctly. If you don't want such "loose ends" you could always write an `after delete` trigger on ContentVersion? Maybe just experiment a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about comparing with FeedItem - I have not used it, but I see @eyescream answer about FeedItem and I'll post here my solution for adding a file to a record with `ContentDocumentLink` and you can choose your right solution.

**createFile method:**

```
public with sharing class File_CTRL {

    public static ContentDocumentLink createFile(Id parentId, String fileName, Blob body, String contentType) {

        // insert a version of the file - if no ContentDocumentId, then it creates a new ContentDocument
        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.ContentLocation = 'S'; // S = within Salesforce, E = External
        cv.VersionData = body;
        cv.Title = fileName;
        cv.PathOnClient = filename;
        insert cv;


        // insert a ContentDocumentLink with the fiel version
        cv = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =: cv.Id LIMIT 1];
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl.ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId;
        cdl.LinkedEntityId = parentId;
        cdl.ShareType = 'V';
        insert cdl;

        return cdl;
    }
}
```

**Example of use - insert file into an account record:**

```
Account acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'myAccount'];
String parentId = acc.Id;
String fileName = 'Attachment 1';
String fileBody = 'Test File Body';
String contentType = 'text/plain';
ContentDocumentLink file = File_CTRL.createFile(parentId, fileName, Blob.valueOf(fileBody), contentType);
```

Comment: Thanks , I  found security wise both the solution are applying security equally So it can be used to solve two different problems like 1. Feed Item when we wana create Feed and Let stakeholders know where as ContentDocumentLink  used while no explicit notification is Required.